# Apache Spark Kafka Streaming getting unlimited jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am running the following Spark program in Java. I am getting data from a Kafka cluster. The problem is that this program is running forever. It is taking RDDs even when there are only three lines of data in Kafka. How do I stop it from taking in more RDDs after the data has been consumed?

The print statements are also not displaying for some reason. I don't know why.

```
public final class SparkKafkaConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
        int numThreads = 3;
        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] topics = "dddccceeffg".split(",");
        for (String topic: topics) {
            topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
        }
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
                KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, "localhost:2181", "NameConsumer", topicMap);
        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                return Lists.newArrayList(COMMA.split(x));
            }
        });
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
                    }
                }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                        return i1 + i2;
                    }
                });
        wordCounts.print();
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

My terminal command is: `C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2 --class "SparkKafkaConsumer" --master local[4] target\simple-project-1.0.jar`

Comment: You're creating a Spark *Streaming* application which reads from Kafka every 2 seconds. If you want to read a single batch, use `KafkaUtils.createRDD`, you don't need a streaming job for that (no need for a `StreamingContext`, etc..)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Is there antway I can stop the streaming when the data is finished?

Comment: You can check if the RDD is empty, and then shutdown the program using `StreamingContext.stop()`. But, this will mean that even if a single batch was empty, your program will shut down, even if 2 seconds later more data is available.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks! Could you answer the seond part of my question?

Comment: Are you actually consuming from a kafka topic? Does it have any data?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, I'm consuming data from a Kafka topic. It has very little data. Just three lines. But `wordCounts.print()` is not printing anything.

Comment: Are you looking at the master node logs/console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118028/discussion-between-khateeb-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes.
Also, is there any way to configure Spark to only fetch RDD only when there is data in Kafka?